# iTunes music syncing between 2 devices but separate Apple IDs

Tags: itunes

I have an iPhone 4S and my son has an IPod 4th generation.  When I set up his iPod, I just synced it with my iTunes music that I selected from my library.

However, now if he uses iMessage, it sends it from MY email address and I also get it in my inbox to me as well.

Is there a way I can change it so he has his own Apple ID and email but in a way that he can sync my music from my iTunes to his iPod??

Answer (score 1):

On the iPod Touch, in the Settings, in the "Messages" section, you can choose the Apple ID used by the device to send iMessages.

Changing this Apple ID should not affect the syncing of the music.